# The value gets copied to the textarea but disappears after a moment

Tags: javascript

I am trying to copy the value of the textbox to the textarea However the value gets copied using the javascript function but it disappears from the textarea after a second. What am i doing wrong?Why does it get disappear after being copied?
this is the html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>
    </title>
    <script src="scripts/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
           <label>Key/Value Pair: </label><input type="text" name="inputText" id="t1"></br></br>
           <label>Key/Value List: </label><br>
           <textarea name="outputText" rows="10" cols="50"  id="t2" ></textarea><br><br>
           <input type="submit" value="Add" onClick="fn_copy()" />
    </form>


</body>
```

and this is the javascript code:

```
function fn_copy()
{
    var temp = document.getElementById("t1").value;
    if(temp != "")
    {
        document.getElementById("t2").value = temp;
    }
    else
        alert("Text is Empty");
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: You're not doing anything to stop the page from reloading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your button type to `button` instead of `submit`. Otherwise your page will be refreshed (default behavior with `submit`) and hence the content of your textarea  reset.

`<input type="button" value="Add" onClick="fn_copy()" />`

Comment: Sadly enough a button element also submits a form in most browsers :P

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are using input of type submit, when you click it, the fuction `fn_copy` execute, but also do a post request, and that is why the value disappears.

Change the input for a button like that and it will work

```js
function fn_copy()
{
    var temp = document.getElementById("t1").value;
    if(temp != "")
    {
        document.getElementById("t2").value = temp;
    }
    else
        alert("Text is Empty");
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label>Key/Value Pair: </label><input type="text" name="inputText" id="t1"><br><br>
  <label>Key/Value List: </label><br>
  <textarea name="outputText" rows="10" cols="50"  id="t2" ></textarea><br><br>
  <button type="button" onclick="fn_copy()">Add</button>
</form>
```

You can sse a working sample here: https://jsfiddle.net/8e5e4wuz/

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp

Use preventdefault to stop it from submitting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Add any id to the button, for example `btn`, and do this:

```
function fn_copy()
{
    var temp = document.getElementById("t1").value;
    if(temp != "")
    {
    document.getElementById("t2").value = temp;
    }
    else
    alert("Text is Empty");
}
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function(event){
    fn_copy();
    event.preventDefault();
})
```